# how can i read data from firebase (one time read ) using (.get)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

how can i get data from document in firebase using the method .get ..... i tried this but it didn't work and gived me an empty string . i already tried another method i found on firebase website :

```
class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;

  GetUserName(this.documentId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
          return Text("Document does not exist");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
```

but it i just need the value to pass it as a parametre like that

```
      String username = "";
                        users.doc(Uid).get().then((value) {
                          username = value.get('Username').toString();
                        });
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code and until last part it looks ok for me.

I think some problem is here:

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}"        
}
```

First of all - try to print your response:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
print('data: $data');
```

Then you can see what exactly is coming from your request. If it is empty - maybe you didn't set up your project and\or firebase correctly.
Or it can be just wrong variable naming you trying to receive.

But the most fun reason could be just that you have empty database with no data in it. Just try to fill it with needed data.

Comment: the first code is working really fine . i already use it in other places .. but here i really want a simple code like the last one in my question .. and i already tried what you said on it , and i am getting a map , and if i print it inside the then() method it works fine but outside it no ,, i don't know wha's the problem

Comment: Could you share what data you receiving it using .then?